# $|z_{1} + z_{2}| = |z_{1} - z_{2}| \implies z_{1}/z_{2}$ is Imaginary

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers, absolute-value

> Two complex numbers $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ are taken such that 
>   $|z_{1} + z_{2}| = |z_{1} - z_{2}|$ and $z_{2}$ is not $0$.
>   Show that $z_{1}/z_{2}$ is purely imaginary, i.e. it has no real part.

So they are both absolute values so
$|z_{1} + z_{2}| = |z_{1} + z_{2}|$ is also true so how can you ever solve it if they are equal or is my assumption false?
also i have tried to turn in into $a + bi$ and got to
$a_{1}\cdot a_{2} = -b_{1}\cdot b_{2}$,
but i dont see how this will help me to get to prove the statement.
Also what it means that $z_{2}$ is not $0$ confuses me because $b$ or $a$ can still be $0$ then but just not both at the same time.

Can someone give me a hint without giving the whole answer? So i can still figure the rest out myself. Just a hint to be able to continue.

Comment: Hint: Think geometrically. What does $|z_1-z_2|$ and $|z_1+z_2|$ mean geometrically? What does $z_1/z_2$ being purely imaginary mean for the geometric relationship between numbers ("vectors", if that suits you better) $z_1$ and $z_2$?

Comment: It is certainly true that $\lvert z_1+z_2\rvert=\lvert z_1+z_2\rvert$, but what does the absolute value have to do with that?

Comment: Hint: Look at $|z_1+z_2|^2=(z_1+z_2)(\bar {z_1}+\bar {z_2})$ and $|z_1-z_2|^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer think geometrically was indeed really usefull. Thank you. I should try to do that more often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$|z_1 + z_2| = |z_1 - z_2| \implies \left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}+1\right| = \left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}-1\right| \tag{1}$$
if $z_2 \neq 0$. In other words, $z_1/z_2$ is equidistant from $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$|z_1 + z_2| = |z_1 - z_2| \iff \left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}+1\right| = \left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}-1\right|\iff \left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}+1\right|^2 = \left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}-1\right|^2$$

and by $w=\frac{z_1}{z_2}$

$$|w+1|^2=|w-1|^2$$

$$(w+1)(\bar w+1)=(w-1)(\bar w-1)$$
$$ |w|^2+w+\bar w+1=|w|^2-w-\bar w+1$$

$$ 2(w+\bar w)=0 \iff \Re(w)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$|z_1 +z_2 |= |z_{1} - z_{2}| Rightarrow|

if z_{2} ne0. In other words, z_{1} / z_{2} is equidistant from 1 and -1.

|z_{1}/z_{2} + 1| = |z_{1}/z_{2} - 1|

As geometrically we know that if a point
Is equidistant from 2  fixed points it lie on the perpendicular bisector of it.
In this case the imaginary axis will act like the perpendicular bisector of of line joining (-1,0) & (1,0)
Therefore, Z1/z2 it will line on the imaginary axis except (0,0) as it is complex no it's y coordinate can't be zero

Comment: Well i am in 11 th only I don't think the solution is correct . But I wrote want came in mind 